# py2exe Usage with Multi-File, Multi-Directory Project Structure

Tags: python, py2exe

My python project has the following structure:

```
+ Project
  -> start.py  --  Main startup script
  -> appstate.json
  +> lib/      --  Directory of third-party libraries such
                   as demjson.py, google gdata, etc.
  +> tools/    --  Directory of my own packages
```

I am not able to figure what options I need to pass to `py2exe` to make it understand the above layout. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I always used py2exe only for python modules and packages. But I expect it should work just by putting the *setup.py* file in your **Project** directory and running it from that directory.

*setup.py*

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sys
import os
sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(console = ['start.py'],
      options = {'py2exe': { }},
      zipfile = None)
```

The dictionary from `'py2exe': { }` can be filled with the some of the following options as needed.

---

**py2exe options, to be specified in the options keyword to the setup function:**

unbuffered - if true, use unbuffered binary stdout and stderr

optimize - string or int (0, 1, or 2)

includes - list of module names to include

packages - list of packages to include with subpackages

ignores - list of modules to ignore if they are not found

excludes - list of module names to exclude

dll_excludes - list of dlls to exclude

dist_dir - directory where to build the final files

typelibs - list of gen_py generated typelibs to include (XXX more text needed)